# Need a one-shot type of delay or similar inside a case statement

Tags: vi, labview

Sorry, cannot post my entire program and I'm not sure how to attach my sample vi to this posting...

I need a one shot in a case statement that functions such that when that particular case is called, it outputs true for 1 second, then changes to false, and the case switches out. Currently, I'm switching cases using a script file decoded in my program, so I cannot switch cases any other way. I've tried nesting a while loop inside, but that only pauses and delays my main while loop, and I can't have that, and I'm concerned that a FOR loop will do the same.

This image is code that I've used elsewhere in my program to make a delay in a similar fashion. This vi gets a "true" signal as an input which changes the outer case to one that pauses until a ms counter completes, while outputting "true", then changing to false as it enters the last case, before returning to the first. The problem is, it can't reset the case until the input is false or else it will re-trigger. Any suggestions?

[image: Sample vi]

Comment: What is wrong about LabVIEWs WAIT function? Do you need your loop to run during that 1s period?

Comment: I would like to help you with your question but actually I dont't really understand what you`re trying to achieve. Could you please try to explain it more clearly? :)

Comment: @sweber yes the loop needs to run during that wait time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the loop running, a 1000ms-wait is not an option. Have a look at the block diagram below. It sends a `True`for one second after you have switched the `Button` (even if you switch the `Button` again within this 1 second window). The 50ms-wait in this loop is just so you won't try to run it at infinite speed... this can be annoying if you wait for an interaction from the Front Panel (but it requires you to memorize the action on the Front Panel, which is why I use a latch-action on the stop button and need to initialize if always to be false... anyway).

[image: Switch]

Comment: great! =) Make sure, you accept the answer if it meets your question, so that others with the same problem find it quickly